# Uploading Image from smartphone using HTML5 and JS

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, smartphone

Is it possible to upload an image from a smartphone's library, like iPhone, using HTML5 and JS? I'm working on an HTML5 site and I need to let the user upload images using a standard form and multipart. I heard that the Phonegap API supports such a functionality, but the question is, is that possible without using wrappers and a native app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a browser, no. The Phonegap API will not work in a web site loaded in a browser. It requires the Java side of the app to work, and thus a full Phonegap application.

Comment: thanks for the help here, is there any workaround to solve such an issue ? or it is just not doable with any technique?

Comment: Have you tried with a "regular" file input element? The user should be able to navigate the SD Card. Less intuitive than what you want to achieve but doable...